# When installing new stud in existing frame, does the stud have to be the *exact* height of the inside of the frame?

Tags: walls, studs, frame

I am about to install two new studs into my wall's frame.  I noticed that the studs are about 1/16th of an inch shorter than the inner height of the frame.  That doesn't appear to be a lot to a layman such as myself, but these studs are going to need to be able to support a layer of drywall and a layer of QuietRock fastened to a hat track that's mounted onto Genie Clips.

One stud is being sistered in directly next to another (thx, Evil Greebo) and the other stud is going right between two studs.  Will the 2 1/2" and 3 1/2" wood screws I will be using to install the studs be enough to counter the 1/16" gap between the top and bottom or will I need to get a longer stud and make an exact cut so that it goes in snug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sistered stud, it makes no difference. All the load is transfered to the adjacent stud and there won't be any movement if you use enough screws and the adjacent stud is properly installed.

For the other side, just make sure the stud is resting firmly against the base plate and screw it down, leaving any slack between the stud and top plate. If there's too much movement, either cut a new stud or put a shim up there. But since none of this is load bearing (in terms of the structure, not your drywall), there's no need for the cuts to be perfect. Just make sure that once installed and screwed in, there isn't any play in the stud, and you'll be fine.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to hear.  Thx!

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "base plate"?

Comment: "base plate" or bottom plate is the 2x4 running along the bottom of the wall, as opposed to the "top plate". The studs are attached to these plates at each end.

Comment: I think if oscil got the new studs within 1/16" on his first try, he did pretty well. Follow BMitch's advise and you will be fine. Reminds me of one of our favorite sayings, "damn, cut the thing three times and it is still too short !"

Comment: @shirlockhomes, you had me laughing at that one when I listened to the podcast. We need a place to keep all these construction related one-liners.

Comment: Just got the studs installed.  The one I sistered in is very stable since it was screwed into another stud.  The one that was installed between two studs is stable where I screwed it in at the top and bottom with 3 1/2" screws, but there is play directly in the middle as I am able to bow it slightly to the left and right.  I put a few diagonal screws into the middle through the stud and into the wall board behind it.  It helped a little, but the center is not stable like the other studs.  Could this pose a potential problem since this stud is going to support the end of the new wall?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin, that's to be expected over an 8' span. The other studs will have less movement if they are secured to the other side (not sure if you have wood sheathing or something else back there). Once you hang the drywall, it won't go anywhere.